# Android System information

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, cordova, lawnchair

I am trying to write a program to write all the android system information accessible from browser as a cookie like ,

- Browser Version
- IP address
- OS
- OS n Browser version
- Plugins browser supported
- Device id if i can

Is it possible to pull all these information using regular java script ? or Jquery ? Or LawnChair? or with HTML5 ? 
or is it possible to link Phonegap native app from the web browser ? if so , how ?

Remember I dont have any native application running on this system to talk to from browser. I am new bie here . any of your suggestions are highly appreciated.

regds

me